# Error within SQL WHERE statement spaceing

Tags: sql, forms

I have the following SQL code:

```
("SELECT doctor_id FROM doctors WHERE doctor_first_name + " " + doctor_last_name =%s", [form.doctor_name.data])
```

But it is not performing the function. I think it is the spacing in between the two database values but have tried every possibility I can think of to get it working and no success.
Thanks

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? What kind of `forms` are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using sql server or   mysql

if you want add  a  space between doctor_first_name and doctor_last_name you could use concat

```
("SELECT doctor_id 
 FROM doctors 
 WHERE concat(doctor_first_name, ' ', doctor_last_name) =%s", [form.doctor_name.data])
```

using oracle  you could use ||

```
("SELECT doctor_id 
 FROM doctors 
 WHERE doctor_first_name|| ' ' || doctor_last_name =%s", [form.doctor_name.data])
```